# Cannot see my controller in self hosted WebApi project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, swagger, autofac

I created a self hosted web api app, to run as a Windows Service, using TopShelf, and Autofac for dependency injection.

Here is my StartUp logic:

```
public class ApiShell : IApiShell
{
    public void Start()
    {
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9090"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Web server running at 'http://localhost:9090'");
        }
    }

    internal class Startup
    {
        //Configure Web API for Self-Host
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
              .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Swagger UI"))
              .EnableSwaggerUi();

            //default route
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

And I start the WebApp as follow:

```
public class HostService
{
    //when windows service statrts
    public void Start()
    {
        IoC.Container.Resolve<IApiShell>().Start();  //start web app
        IoC.Container.Resolve<IActorSystemShell>().Start();
    }

    //when windows service stops
    public void Stop()
    {
        IoC.Container.Resolve<IActorSystemShell>().Stop();
    }
}
```

TopShelf configuration:

```
HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<HostService>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new HostService());
                s.WhenStarted(sn => sn.Start());
                s.WhenStopped(sn => sn.Stop());
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            x.SetDescription("Sample Service");
            x.SetDisplayName("Sample Service");
            x.SetServiceName("Sample Service");
        });
```

My controller:

```
public class PingController : ApiController
{
    private IActorSystemShell _actorSystem;

    public PingController(IActorSystemShell actorSystem)
    {
        _actorSystem = actorSystem;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Ping()
    {
        var response = await _actorSystem.PingActor.Ask<PingMessages.Pong>(PingMessages.Ping.Instance(), 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        return response.PongMessage;
    }
}
```

I installed Swagger as well, but I can't reach my controller, using either of the following attempts:

> http://localhost:9090/api/Ping
>
> http://localhost:9090/swagger

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you need `{action}`?

Comment: @john Why would I need action?  This is a web api controller

Comment: You have a spelling error in `{contorller}` don't know if that might be it?

Comment: @spersson I was really hoping that would fix it, but it did not. Thanks for telling about the spelling error

Comment: @monstertjie_za Please fix it in your question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do this:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9090"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Web server running at 'http://localhost:9090'");
}
```

After the write line, there's no more statements left in the using, so the using will close, thus stopping the web app. This is one of those cases where even though the result of `WebApp.Start` is an [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), you shouldn't use a using statement. Instead, do this:

```
public class ApiShell : IApiShell
{
    _IDisposable _webApp;

    public void Start()
    {
        _webApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9090");
        Console.WriteLine($"Web server running at 'http://localhost:9090'");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _webApp.Dispose();
    }
}

public class HostService
{
    public void Start()
    {
        IoC.Container.Resolve<IApiShell>().Start();  //start web app
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        IoC.Container.Resolve<IApiShell>().Stop();  //stop web app
    }
}
```

You haven't shown your dependency registration, but make sure that `IApiShell` is registered as a singleton so you're starting/stopping the same instance.

Note, if this were a traditional console app instead of a Windows service, you could do this:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9090"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Web server running at 'http://localhost:9090'");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

The ReadKey method would keep the using statement active and thus keep the web app from disposing.

Comment: I figured this yes, removed the using statement, and I still could not connect to the controllers, but I was now getting the an exception, where it requires my controller to have a default parameterless constructor.  It is now not picking up the Injected instance in the constructor of the controller. Adding a parameterless contructor, I could connect to my controller

Comment: @monstertjie_za That sounds like a separate issue. Sounds like you haven't set the dependency resolver as shown [in the documentation](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html). If you can't figure it out, I think that'd be a second question.

Comment: I agree on the second question.  Will read the documentation again, might have missed something.

Comment: @monstertjie_za You need some line like `config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);`

Comment: I have that added, but will try and figure this new problem out, if I don't come right, I will Register each controller individually ;-)